# compact Zariski-dense subgroups of p-adic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups, local-fields

Given an algebraic group $G$ defined over a $\mathbb Q_p$. It has two topologies: one is induced by the $p$-adic metric, the other is the Zariski topology. Let $C$ be a compact (w.r.t. the $p$-adic topology on $G(\mathbb Q_p)$), Zariski-dense subgroup of $G(\mathbb Q_p)$, must $C$ contain an open compact subgroup of $G(\mathbb Q_p)$?

For example, let $G$ be the affine line over $\mathbb Q_p$, the question in this case is equivalent to whether any infinite compact subgroup of $\mathbb Q_p$ is of the form $p^n\mathbb Z_p$.

Sorry if the question is not appropriate here but I'd appreciate any comments.

Comment: It seems you are abusing notation by writing $G$ to denote both an algebraic group over $F$ and for its group of $F$-points; these should not be conflated with each other.  Anyway, if $H$ is a connected linear algebraic group over $\mathbf{Q}_p$ and $G = H_F$ is its scalar extension to $F$ then the Zariski topology on $G(F)$ arising from that on $G$ makes any compact open subgroup $C$ of $H(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ Zariski-dense in $G(F)$ but such $C$ is never open in $G(F)$ when $[F:\mathbf{Q}_p]>1$.  Maybe you only care about $F=\mathbf{Q}_p$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the confusions. I just revised it.

Comment: Your revision doesn't make sense because it is meaningless to speak of $\mathbf{Q}_p$-points of an $F$-group that hasn't been equipped with a structure of descent to a $\mathbf{Q}_p$-group. Since $G(F)$ is topologically identified with $({\rm{R}}_{F/\mathbf{Q}_p}(G))(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ (points of Weil restriction) and the Zariski topologies of $G$ and ${\rm{R}}_{F/\mathbf{Q}_p}(G)$ have little to do with each other, it seems that your consideration of general $F$ is a red herring and you only want to consider $F=\mathbf{Q}_p$ (by renaming ${\rm{R}}_{F/\mathbf{Q}_p}(G)$ as $G$), right?

Comment: Here are counterexamples to the converse with $F=\mathbf{Q}_p$. The $\mathbf{Q}_p$-group $G={\rm{GL}}_1 \times {\rm{GL}}_1$ has only countably many connected proper Zariski-closed subgroups, so one can pick a line $L$ in ${\rm{Lie}}(G)$ avoiding the tangent spaces to all such proper subgroups (since $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is uncountable). A small compact neighborhood of 0 in $L$ exponentiates to a *non-open* compact subgroup $C$ of $G(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ whose Zariski closure has identity component that cannot be a proper $\mathbf{Q}_p$-subgroup of $G$, so $C$ is Zariski-dense in $G$.

Comment: @nfdc23 precisely the line $L$ should be irrational, i.e. define an element outside $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbf{Q})$ (it's rational iff it's the Lie algebra of a 1-dimensional subtorus).

Comment: On the other hand, if $G$ is semisimple and $C$ is a compact Zariski-dense subgroup then $C$ is open. Indeed, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{c}$ of $C$ is $C$-invariant for the adjoint representation, hence is $G$-invariant by Zariski density, so $\mathfrak{c}$ is an ideal. So we can write $G=AB$ with $A\cap B$ finite so that $C$ has a finite index subgroup contained in $A$ (which is the semisimple factor of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{c}$). The image of $C$ in $G/A$ is finite and hence by Zariski density we deduce $G=A$, and thus $C$ is open.